# Modifying Java indentation style

Tags: indentation, java

I use Emacs for Android development and this has been bugging me lately.

I'm trying to get the following indentation behaviour:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    submitEnquiry();
  }
});
```

and with my current setup I'm getting this:

```
submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      submitEnquiry();
    }
  });
```

Quite a specific case I know, but one that I'm running into very often. I'm using Emacs 24.4 and I'm only modifying `c-basic-offset` in my `java-mode-hook` at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some poking around, it looks like this has fixed it (getting called in `java-mode-hook`):

```
(c-set-offset 'inexpr-class 0)
```

By default it is set to `+`. `inexpr-class` controls the indentation level for anonymous classes and anonymous initialisation.